# JSONP+jQuery : Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

I have a WCF JSONP service that I am trying to utilitze with jQuery (v 1.7.2).

Server side code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

[JSONPBehavior(callback = "method")]
List<string> GetList()
{
    return new List<string> {"test1", "test2"};
}
```

Client side code:

```
function showList()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mysite/myservice.svc/GetList',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { },
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (m)
            {
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (err)
            {
                debugger;
            }
            });
        }
```

What happens is: 'error' callback is called and when I check `err` parameter, its `err.responseText` contains the correct JSON response: `{"GetListResult":["test1","test2"]}`

To see what's going on I went into debugging jQuery itself, and what I see is that it fails to convert the result `ajaxConvert` method:

jQuery 1.7.2 (not minimized), line 7511: `success = ajaxConvert( s, response );` those exception `Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.`.

When I step through `ajaxConvert`, i see that it tries to do `jQuery.globalEval(response)` which throws the aforementioned exception.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your `dataType` ought to be "jsonp"?  What if you set it to "json" ?  I don't think you are doing jsonp.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: I need to do a cross domain call - wcf service is in a different domain than the client page; thus I need a JSONP call.

Answer (score 0):

Is the JSON output wrapped in a callback function? A crucial part of JSONP is that it essentially passes json data to a function that gets executed into the javascript scope.

The name of the function should be appended onto the the request URL automatically by jQuery, ie the request should be: `http://mysite/myservice.svc/GetList?callback=jQuery_random1231`

Then your JSONP output should be this:

```
jQuery_random1231({ key: 'value', key1: 'value1' .. });
```

Your backend obviously has to cater for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your service is not returning JSONP but JSON instead. The eval function tries to evaluate the string as JavaScript code - if that would be a JSONP format, the function would succeed with the evaluation. The actual JSONP response should be: method({"GetListResult":["test1","test2"]}).

I suppose that you are using the JSONPBehavior from the [MSDN sample here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You can try to debug the behavior to see if it works correctly. Personally I had an issue with this class while serializing raw streams to JSONP.

If you are in .NET 4 you do not need to use this behaviour any more. You can instead change the configuration of the binding in web.config:

```
<binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
```

The other thing you might try is to use the [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method instead of the ajax method. I am using that one with JSONP and it works.

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: You are right, I am using that example. Unfortunately I can't use .NET 4.0. So, if I use getJSON() will it still work cross-domain?

Comment: Yes in my scenario I use getJson() for crossdomain calls. But I think it is more server side problem. You can even verify using Chrome that JSONP is returned correctly or that pure JSON is returned. If you are sure that server returns JSONP then move to jQuery debuging :). but not before

Comment: It looks like the server is returning JSON as the response is just json string. I followed Microsoft example, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: OK actually to test that JSONP is working correctly you have to compose the right url. For example for URL like this: http://server/myservice?callback=wrapper you should recieve a response like: wrapper(..original JSON here...).

So you can use getJSON method of jQuery but you have to add the ?callback=wrapper at the end. Check the jQuery docs on this one. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found as solution yet but this might help. I had the same problem and tracked things down with the debugger. I eventually discovered the cause was a query string parameter. Everything worked once I removed the querystring parameter from the webservice call. I hope this helps

http://senseicris.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/jquery-error-80020101-a-fix